# How To Get Two-Way binding from RadioButton to title with ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

When I change the radiobutton value, I want the title to reflect the change. For textboxes, this works but not for radiobutton groups. I've got the code below and a fiddle example that shows it.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1abr

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestViewModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

        alias: 'viewmodel.test', 

        data: {
            rg: 'BBB'
        }
    });

    Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestView', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        layout: 'form',


        viewModel: {
            type: 'test'  // references alias "viewmodel.test"
        },

        bind: {
            title: 'Hello {rg}'
        },


        items: [{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            columns: 1,
            width: 600,
            horizontal: true,
            bind: {
                value: {
                    rg: 'BBB'
                }
            },
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'A',
                inputValue: 'AAA',
                name: 'rg'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'B',
                inputValue: 'BBB',
                name: 'rg'
            },{
                boxLabel: 'C',
                inputValue: 'CCC',
                name: 'rg'
            }]
        }]
    });

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.TestView', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 700
        });
    });
```

Comment: I managed to get this working but adding a listener but I'm thinking there should be someway to do this with just databinding.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ac0

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1acf